# Replace svg with svg-inkscape to get rid of subfig

Tags: macros, graphics, subfloats, paths, svg

I would like to include SVG images in my LaTeX document. I also would like to use `subcaption` for subfigures. I am using the following folder structure:

- `<project path>/Document/document.tex` for the document itself
- `<project path>/Pics/*.svg` for the images

I tried the package `svg`, but it auto-loads `subfig`, which is not compatible with `subcaption`.

So I tried to use the macros described in [svg-inkscape](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/svg-inkscape):

```
\newcommand{\executeiffilenewer}[3]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\pdffilemoddate{#1}}%
  {\pdffilemoddate{#2}}>0%
  {\immediate\write18{#3}}\fi%
}
\newcommand{\includesvg}[1]{%
  \executeiffilenewer{#1.svg}{#1.pdf}%
  {inkscape -z -D --file=#1.svg %
  --export-pdf=#1.pdf --export-latex}%
  \input{#1.pdf_tex}%
}
```

To use it, the following syntax must be used:

```
\begin{figure}
\def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
\includesvg{image}
\end{figure}
```

It works, but it has problems loading images from the relative path defined like the following:

```
\graphicspath{{../Pics/}}
```

I can work around this by putting `../Pics/` in front of every filename.

How do I need to change the macro suggested in [svg-inkscape](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/svg-inkscape) to do the following?

- Use the path defined in `\graphicspath{}`
- Use the same syntax as `\includesvg{width=...}{<path to svg file>}` in `svg` (remove `\def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}` and add `{width=...}` to `\includesvg` instead)

Modifying `svg` to remove the dependency to `subfig` is not an option, because my document needs to be compatible to other LaTeX installations.